# Copy/clone parts of an object?

Tags: php, oop

I have an object $stdClassObject that's created by json_decode. It's for train schedules. I need to be able to create a new object which contains just those trains heading east bound. I'm at a loss of how to do this since I'm very new to Objects in PHP. Here is the PHP code I've isolate $trips[$ny_trip]:

```
// $stdClassObject originally created by json_decode
foreach ($trips as $ny_trip=>$ny_trip_info) {

    if (East_Bound($ny_trip_info->DESTINATION)) {
    // Copy or clone(?) $trips[$ny_trip]) to an object called east_bound
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I should mention that there is going to be more than one East Bound train and this IF statement is to cloning over the selected ones from $trips[0 to N].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

- Implement the magic method [`__clone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to be able to customize the process of cloning
- Add a custom function for this to your class. Like `YourClass::customClone($options)`

Looks like  that the first option suites very well here

Comment: Can I implement the clone technique without redefining the complete structure of the original object that was created in my code example from json_decode?

Comment: No, this isn't possible unfortunately as `json_decode()` will give you always a stdclass object. I would advice you to create a special class, let's say `CustomizedObjectClonery` and add functionality there